# Connecting WiiMote with Win8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, bluetooth, wii, wiimote

I am developing a game in Unity using C# that uses the Wiimote (more details [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/100468/interfacing-wiimote-with-unity-5/)). I was using win7 and all I had to do was turn my bluetooth one and turn the WiiMote on as-well. But I migrated to Win8.1 and this method no longer works.

Is there something specific that I need to do for win8.1 to find my wiimote?

Comment: The driver you are using supports Windows 8.1?

Comment: I am not using a driver but rather a simple dll, is anything else needed?
I found the dll here
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UniWii

Comment: Does Windows see the device?  Are you able to pair it?  The driver you would be using would be the Bluetooh device driver.

Comment: the application crashes when trying to run it with a not responding error. How can I check if device is visible etc? Is there a way to pair with the device from windows instead of my code?

Comment: You pair it just like any Bluetooth device.  It just won't be an input device without the framework you mentioned.

Comment: Using the metro pc settings->devices->bluetooth? there I can see it

Comment: Alright.  So the device is connected.  This means the only possible explaination is that framework your attempting to use does not support Windows 8.  If its an open source framework you could debug the problem and determine the exact cause of the exception.

Comment: You are welcome to self-answer it yourself.  I don't need the reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing connection with the device via windows and trying to pair with it everything seems to work properly and the device is connected.

Which leads to the conclusion that the driver/framework I am using does not support Windows 8 and that is why I cannot communicate with the WiiMote from my code